# The Official Stack Exchange Spelling Bee, sponsored by *something something*

Tags: knowledge, cipher, steganography

Behold, the First annual official amaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazing Puzzling Stack Exchange Spelling Bee! With hard words! Harder puzzles! And conveniently pre-signed-upped competitors!!!

*insert canned applause*

Well, let's introduce our contestants!

We have, from abroad,

Our Colombian Friend, Bernardo Recaman Santos! (Did I say that right?)

Next, we have, from Canada, Don Kirkby, eh?

Dannyu NDos, from South Korea!

Cap, from... uh... I don't think he filled out the sign-up sheet, he's just here.

Then, uh... He's Nobody. I'm nobody, please stand up! *Laughter*. What?

Then, one of the most famous, Prim3numbah!

Our Bri'ish friend, STIV!!!

And finally, last but not least, a mathematician, Rob Pratt!

**tv coverage cuts out**

Deusovi gets up. "Ugh. Why does it do this?!"

Beastly Gerbil says, "Well, maybe it's cuz we're a smaller SE."

Ugh.

It cuts back in after an hour.

And our winner is Stiv!

How do you feel about spelling23640190

*AUGHHHHHHHHHH*

"No worries. I've already figured out how Stiv won."

How did Stiv win the bee?

Hint One:

> Deusovi stands up and says, "They've done this format in other places. The people change, not the competitors. It happens every month. If only the word would have been something like fouette, then I could have TROUNCED xyldke and co."

Hint Two

> Remember, everyone, that this is solvable only until the END OF THIS MONTH. So Hurry. Meanwhile, outside... a sign is being held by a lone protestor, named **Hinty McHintface**. It says **"LETTERS ARE PEOPLE TOO!"**

Comment: Mandatory Meta post reference: [Should we be referencing/using specific users in puzzles?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/should-we-be-referencing-using-specific-users-in-puzzles)

Comment: If anybody featured in this puzzle doesn't want to be, I'll be fine with that and remove them.

Comment: I could use a completely different group of people, if the community would want.

Comment: He won the bee because Stiv is in your head...always.